# Maintain aspect ratio when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

So I needed my code to have the images maintain the aspect ratio they are currently set at regardless of whether or not the user is viewing the site on a smaller screen or if they resize their browser instead of viewing it full screen.

Here's some code I have so far but I am just unsure what to do while still keeping the current effects intact (that being that the images are side by side and aligned in the center).

```
<style>
.first-image {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
.second-image {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```
<body>
<center>
<div class="first-image">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/leftbryce.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/whiteleftbryce.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/leftbryce.png'" width="800 px" height="auto"></a>
</div>

<div class="second-image">
    <img src="img/whiterightbryce.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/rightbryce.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/whiterightbryce.png'" width="800 px" height="auto">
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link for demo:- http://codepen.io/JDabhi/pen/aJNqwa

CSS

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
center {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 
}
.first-image {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
.second-image {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: How can I keep the images aligned in the center though? And is there a way to have them fill the screen?

Comment: center align parent div or image i don't get you ?

Comment: I need both of the images to align in the center

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your images in a div, then set the image width as a percentage rather than a pixel size.

Answer (score 0):

give the width to your div and image width should be always `100%`.

```css
<style type="text/css">
div{max-width:400px;}
img{max-width:100%;}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="first-image">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Venice_Italy-620x387.jpg" onmouseover="http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Venice_Italy-620x387.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Venice_Italy-620x387.jpg'"></a>
</div>

<div class="second-image">
    <img src="http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Venice_Italy-620x387.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Venice_Italy-620x387.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.youramazingplaces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Venice_Italy-620x387.jpg'">
</div>
```